# Sharing Data Between Controllers, Angularjs 1.3 version

Tags: angularjs

I am working on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jq2RQ/), it is in angularjs 1.2.17
However when I try the [same script](http://jsfiddle.net/Jq2RQ/1/) with angularjs 1.3.14 it gives error, see console.

Finally when I try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m16un1Lp/1/) again with 1.3.14 version:

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <div ng-controller="firstctrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.msg" />
         <h1>{{data.msg}}</h1>

    </div>
    <div ng-controller="secondctrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.msg" />
         <h1>{{data.msg}}</h1>

    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('Data', function () {
    return {
        msg: "I am data from a service"
    };
});
app.controller('firstctrl', ['$scope', function($scope, Data){
    $scope.data = Data;
}]);
app.controller('secondctrl', ['$scope', function($scope, Data){
    $scope.data = Data;
}]);
```

I could not make it work: It does not give error but `data.msg` does not update in both controller.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use sensitive keys such as `Data` or `data` also not forget to include dependencies [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m16un1Lp/2/)

Comment: It is nice to find answer immediatly on SO, after spending hours on the issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is related to how angular wires the controllers with the module (app), the right way to do declare a controller is like in this modified version of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J_Armando/yozczakx/):

`//... your code
    myApp.controller('firstctrl', ['$scope', 'Data', function ($scope, data) {
      $scope.data = data;
    }]);`

As you can see `firstctrl` now works as expected.

Your third fiddle doesn't work because you are not injecting the factory on the controller's declaration function.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the 'Data' identifier to the array in controller.

My answer is below:

```
app.controller('firstctrl', ['$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data){
    $scope.data = Data;
}]);
app.controller('secondctrl', ['$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data){
    $scope.data = Data;
}]);
```